# Javascript detect when a promise resolves in an array of promises

Tags: javascript

This question relates to a VSCode extension. There is no Browser involved.

I issue blocks of 5 REST api calls which I then save in an array - promiseArray.
I then issue a `Promise.all(promiseArray).then((result) => {...}`
Then I start my next block of 5 REST api calls.

There can be many REST calls involved and I limit them to 5 so as to not overload the server.
This is all working fine but I am having to wait for all 5 to be resolved before proceeding and I would ideally like to detect when any REST call resolves so I can then issue my next REST call - in order to maintain 5 running at a time.
So far I have not been able to determine how to do this.

As a test, I have tried adding `.then((result) => {...}`
but it doesn't fire until it hits my existing `Promise.all(promiseArray)` statement - which I am trying to replace!

My second problem is that I need to know which particular REST call is resolved within my array of 5. As I then need to insert my next REST call into the promiseArray at that same offset.
That is necessary because my REST call contains a token which cannot be used across calls concurrently, so I assign the token from a parallel token array using the offset value.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try to use a `forEach` loop and the `await` keyword ?

Comment: You can do `Promise.all(promiseArray).then(resultArray => { /*  */ })` to get the result of your calls.

Comment: Do you really use `promiseArray.then`, or is that a copying error?

Comment: You can use [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to continue when you get the first response.

Comment: I don't think you need to do this yourself. Browsers have built-in limits on the number of concurrent requests they'll make to a single server.

Comment: @Barmar Node.js doesn't limit requests though

Comment: I think it’s called a queue.  Search "JavaScript fetch queue".  See for example https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/implementing-an-async-queue-in-23-lines-of-code

Comment: @Barmar If you simply try to make as many `fetch` requests as possible, Chrome kills them due to limits (a network error, I believe; like DNS and CORS and such). You have to rate limit the creation of the requests yourself.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I didn't know that, I assumed it would limit them similarly to the way it limits requests that come from parsing the HTML (fetching images, scripts, and iframes).

Comment: I know that by hard experience, implementing a solution for a similar scenario to the one described here :). I ended up using a custom version of  [`p-map`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-map). That was made for Node, though, so I am hoping to get some time to make a simpler, cleaner implementation.

Comment: Just to point oit that there is no browser involved in running of this code. This is a VSCode Extension. I am making a number (a lot)f of REST calls to the mainframe  and I limit the number of concurrent calls to 5 at a time.  The token passed is a logon token that  has been previously created and verified and so avoids the unnecessary logon/logoff sequence (saves about 1 second per call).  The token can only be in use once at any point in time. That is why I need to know which promise within the array of 5 was resolved so I can only then reuse its assigned token.

Comment: @Prekar Sola -I am already doing that. I don't want to wait till all 5 are resolved. Ideally I want to start my next Rest call as soon as 1 of the 5 completes so that there are always at least 5 running all the time.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm, I may be incorrect. At least, I can't reproduce that behavior anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function (`queueManager`) which is picks up a piece of data from a queue and passes it to your function which creates the promise (`processor`).

When `processor`'s promise resolves, `queueManager` can call itself recursively to pull the next piece of data from the queue, create a new promise and return that.

If the resolved value is another promise, then that promise will get adopted.

At some point the queue will run out of data, so at that point you should just resolve the promise with a regular value (or nothing) so that the recursion stops.

---

Once you have a queueManager, you can run multiple of them in parallel so that you have (for example) 5 things from the queue being worked on at once.

Then you can put those 5 queueManager promises into an array and pass it to `Promise.all` so you know when they are **all** finished.

```js
const dataQueue = [5000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 3000, 2000, 4000, 1000, 5000];

const results = [];

const processor = (data) => {
  console.log(`Starting with ${data}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Finished with ${data}`);;
      resolve(`Data was ${data}`)
    }, data)
  });
}

const queueManager = async() => {
  if (dataQueue.length === 0) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  const input = dataQueue.shift()
  const output = await processor(input);
  results.push(output);
  return queueManager();
}

Promise.all([queueManager(), queueManager(), queueManager(), queueManager(), queueManager()]).then(() => console.log(results));
```

Comment: It's not guaranteed that `results` is in the same order as `dataQueue`, because one request can overtake another.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you should create 5 promises that each runs a while-loop picking out elements from a list and turning them into API calls (like a queue).

I am not sure how this would work with the situation mentioned in your second problem. If I'm understanding correctly, you have 5 tokens that can be used for authorizing with the API? In that case you can just use one token for each of the 5 promises.

Comment: No,  a token can only be in use one REST call at any one time. Only when the REST call is completed(resolved) and the token freed up can it then be used in a subsequent REST call.   That is why i need to know which REST call completed, so I can the reuse the same logon token for a subsequent call.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood it as well - then I just explained myself poorly. You basically just want to use multi-threading to split the API calls across 5 different threads. There are various ways to do this, but the approach mentioned above with Promises should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The code below initially invokes the function `scheduleNextRequest` 5 times with 5 different tokens and then again whenever a previous request has been completed, using the same token in the new request as in the completed one. This guarantees that there are 5 requests running with different tokens at all times (until `makeNextRequest` returns false, because there is nothing more to do).

`scheduleNextRequest` returns a promise that settles when there are no more requests to be processed. When all 5 have settled, the results of all requests are available in `results`.

```js
var total = 0;
var results = [];

function makeNextRequest(token) {
  var random = 1000 * Math.random();
  return !done.checked && new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(random);
    }, random);
  });
}

function scheduleNextRequest(token) {
  var req = makeNextRequest(token);
  if (req) {
    document.getElementById(token).checked = true;
    var resultIndex = total;
    totalCounter.textContent = ++total;
    return req.then(function(result) {
      results[resultIndex] = result;
      document.getElementById(token).checked = false;
      return scheduleNextRequest(token);
    });
  } else
    return Promise.resolve();
}

Promise.all([
  scheduleNextRequest("token1"),
  scheduleNextRequest("token2"),
  scheduleNextRequest("token3"),
  scheduleNextRequest("token4"),
  scheduleNextRequest("token5")
]).then(function() {
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="token1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="token2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="token3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="token4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="token5" />
<span id="totalCounter"></span>
<input type="checkbox" id="done" /> All done
```

(This example does not make real requests, it simulates them by waiting for a random period.)